# How to prompt error on TextInput

Tags: java, android

I just want to show a error prompt on `TextInput` while the user is typing. 
For example, I want to show `Password is too short` error while user is typing on `TextInput` if input length is less than 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is with Text Input Layout

[image: Something like this]

in xml Layout file

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/textView_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Your activity should be something like this.

```
passwordTIL = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout_password);
passwordET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textVIew_password);


passwordET.addTextChangedListener(new SigninTextWatcher(passwordET)

//you can use this for username too or to check if the email format is correct or not.

private class SigninTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
        private View view;

        private SigninTextWatcher(View view) {
            this.view = view;
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.textView_password:
                    validatePassword();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }


    private boolean validatePassword() {
        if (passwordET.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            passwordTIL.setError("Empty error message");
            requestFocus(passwordET);
            return false;
        } else if(passwordET.getText().toString().length() < 6){
                passwordTIL.setError("Short password error message");
                requestFocus(passwordET);
                return false;
        }else {
                passwordTIL.setErrorEnabled(false);
            }
            return true;
        }
```

You can make use of validatePassword() function to enable/ disable login button too

Answer (score 0):

You can use textChangedListener attached to your edit text.
See simple example:

```
Field1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if(s.length() < 6)
       // show message too short
    }}

   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
   int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override    
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
   int before, int count) {

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
et_password.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            if(charSequence.length()<6){
                et_password.setError("The password must contain 6 characters");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Could the downvoter explain the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Add addTextChangedListener() to your editText.

```
    EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_et);

    password.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
          if((charSequence.toString()).length < 6){
           Toast.makeText(this, "Password length less than 6", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
});
```