# Android manage warning messages in edittext

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext

Please let me know that how i can achieve this.
I have an edittext for email , If i have entered nothing then instead of showing alert or toast.
Hint will convert to red color.

If i have have entered wrong email then entered text convert to red. and when i start typing again it will convert to black color.

If error

- (Nothing entered ) hint red
- (When start entering) hint convert to black
- (if not valid email) email entered converted to red.
- (When start reentering) email text convert to red.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45158144/3983054

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom edittext

```
public class EditTextLight extends EditText {
    public EditTextLight(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setTypeface(ApplicationFonts.getLightFont(context));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter) {
        if (getTag() != null) {
            setTextColor(Color.parseColor(getTag().toString()));
        }
    }

     if (YOUR VALIDATION) 
{edittext.setHint(Validations.setErrorSpanText(edittext.getHint().toString()));
            }

 public static Spannable setErrorSpanText(String message) {
        Spannable textToSpan = new SpannableString(message);
        textToSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, message.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        return textToSpan;
    }

 if (edittext.getText().length() == 0)
                    edittext.setHint(Validations.setErrorSpanText(edittext.getHint().toString()));
                else {
                    edittext.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }
```

Comment: Yes it works thanks for the help , But i still need to refine this there is 1 issue with it.

Thanks a lot buddy

Answer (score 0):

Your `EditText` will look like this

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:hint="Enter email here"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:textColorHint="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
```

In your activity:-

```
final EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    email.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
            if (isValidEmail(email.getText().toString().trim())) {
                email.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            } else
            {
                email.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {

        }
    });
```

and add this function to check email validation:-

```
 public final static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
    if (target == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();
    }
}
```

For more customization you can edit `addTextChangedListener` and play around with its function

Answer (score -1):

You should use Text Input Layout for that one.

Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/45158144/5130133

Comment: A short answer is not an answer but a comment.